# MySQL to Mysqli - Database Class - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-7

I updated my server to the new PHP 7, because so far i was using PHP 5.
But the database class is not working anymore, so i want to convert the MySql function to Mysqli.
I want to modify this function to mysqli, can someone helpe me?
Thanks

```
function query($s='',$rows=false,$organize=true) {
    if (!$q=mysql_query($s,$this->con)) return false;
    if ($rows!==false) $rows = intval($rows);
    $rez=array(); $count=0;
    $type = $organize ? MYSQL_NUM : MYSQL_ASSOC;
    while (($rows===false || $count<$rows) && $line=mysql_fetch_array($q,$type)) {
        if ($organize) {
            foreach ($line as $field_id => $value) {
                $table = mysql_field_table($q, $field_id);
                if ($table==='') $table=0;
                $field = mysql_field_name($q,$field_id);
                $rez[$count][$table][$field]=$value;
            }
        } else {
            $rez[$count] = $line;
        }
        ++$count;
    }
    if (!mysql_free_result($q)) return false;
    return $rez;
}
```

MySqli Version (but it's incomplete):

```
function query($s='',$rows=false,$organize=true) {
    if (!$q=mysqli_query($this->con,$s)) return false;
    if ($rows!==false) $rows = intval($rows);
    $rez=array(); $count=0;
    $type = $organize ? MYSQLI_NUM : MYSQLI_ASSOC;
    while (($rows===false || $count<$rows) && $line=mysqli_fetch_array($q,$type)) {
        if ($organize) {
            foreach ($line as $field_id => $value) {
                $table = mysql_field_table($q, $field_id);
                if ($table==='') $table=0;
                $field = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($q,$field_id)->name;
                $rez[$count][$table][$field]=$value;
            }
        } else {
            $rez[$count] = $line;
        }
        ++$count;
    }
    if (!mysqli_free_result($q)) return false;
    return $rez;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: specifically what's the issue?

Comment: Please add the problem you're actually having and all relevant information pertaining to it. At the moment it just sounds like a "please do this for me".

Comment: The PHP manual is what you would use to help you convert this function/method...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should enable MySQLi Extension.

For windows:

uncomment in php.ini

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

and for linux:

uncomment in php.ini

```
extension=php_mysqli.so
```

in Ubuntu its located at

```
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

If this is not solving your problem, please share more informations.